# Обособление приложений перед именем собственным

Tags: приложение

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении? Кажется, дополнительного обстоятельственного значения здесь нет.

Мое видение роли ЛЕГО в развитии детской способности творчества поддерживает специалистка, кандидат педагогических наук (,) дальше идут фамилия и инициалы, профессионально занимающаяся этим вопросом.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна.

...поддерживает специалистка(ка?!), кандидат наук Иванова А.А., профессионально занимающаяся...

Может, всё-таки "специалист"?

Comment: Посмотрела в интернете... Это слово есть в словарях, напр. [здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/229798).

Comment: Слово-то есть, я не отрицаю. Но оно всё-таки больше разговорного стиля, как секретарша или даже врачиха.

Answer (score 1):

Приложение, стоящее перед именем собственном, не обособляется.

Ср.: Капитан пограничных войск Иванов служил на Дальнем Востоке.

директор Института внешней торговли, кандидат технических наук,
**доцент И. М. Лебедев.**